# Vista loads two logon screens at system boot

Tags: windows-vista, login, duplicate

I recently reformatted my hard drive and reinstalled Vista as the operating system.

Now when I boot the machine, two logon prompts are shown. I noticed as I would start typing my password and then the textbox would lose focus. I was confused as to why this would happen until I noticed that when I press Alt-Tab, there are two logon screens available. One has focus on the Password box, the other doesn't.

I have never seen this before (I have reformatted several times previously without incident) and it is rather irritating. I'd like to find out why this occurs and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm simply an idiot. I hadn't installed Service Pack 2.

When I installed Service Pack 2, it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a laptop with a fingerprint reader or other bio-metric device? Or even a desktop with similar hardware? I've seen this happen before when a system comes preloaded for devices that capture fingerprints.

If so, I would disable the hardware and more importantly, uninstall any OEM software related to bio-metric logins to start.

Comment: It's on a standard desktop with none of those devices. I'll check the drivers etc. in case it thinks there is for some reason.